# Need help to create a Jolt specification

Tags: jolt

Need help with a JOLT specification for converting the JSON from the shared input format to the expected format.

```json
[
  {
    "Header": {
        "TeamCD": 2
    },
    "Player": [
               {
                 "PlayerNumber": 1,
                 "ShortName": "John",
                 "UniformNO": 11,
                 "SmartStart": 20200201,
                 "SmartEnd": 99999999
               }, 
               {
                 "PlayerNumber": 2,
                 "ShortName": "James",
                 "UniformNO": 12,
                 "SmartStart": 20200201,
                 "SmartEnd": 99999999
               }
              ]
  }
]
```

Desired output:

```json
[
    {
      "Field": "TeamCD",
      "Type": "20"
      "Value": 2,
      "Vendor": "Vendor1"
    },
    {
    "Field": "PlayerNumber",
    "Type": "23"
    "Value": 1,
    "Vendor": "Vendor1"
  },
  {
    "Field": "ShortName",
    "Type": "24"
    "Value": "John",
    "Vendor": "Vendor1"
  },
  {
    "Field": "PlayerNumber",
    "Type": "23"
    "Value": 2,
    "Vendor": "Vendor1"
  },
  {
    "Field": "ShortName",
    "Type": "24"
    "Value": "James",
    "Vendor": "Vendor1"
  }
]
```

I am trying to achieve this using JoltTransformJSON now. Is this achievable using JoltTransformJSON? I have it running on Nifi, if not possible with Jolt what are my options?

Comment: but there are no correlation between input and desired output for the values of the some keys such as `Vendor`, `Type`.. What's the logic behind?

Comment: indeed, those fields Vendor and Type I have to added, Type can be different depend on each field.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thanks for your help, it was clear that fields needs to have correlation between.